# What is the best practice to transfer a class or an interface to another project or computer?

Tags: java, eclipse, rmi

I am writing simple code to try java rmi.

On the server side i wrote the interface and the implementation class of the object.

What is the correct way (on eclipse, if it makes any difference) to import the interface i created in the server project to the client project?
I need a solution that imitates that i am writing the server on a computer and the client on a different one.

Thank you for your help, here is the client code, Car is the interface i need to import.

```
package rmiClient;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class MainClient {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws RemoteException {
                Registry reg = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("localhost", 9999);
                Car ferrari = (Car) reg.lookup("supercar");
        }
}
```

Comment: You could make a library out of the shared parts.

Comment: @Henry Thank you this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Either include server project as a dependency - but in you misconfigure that it can be include into the client artifact - or keep shared parts as separate project and include it in both server and client projects